# How to check click events on social share buttons, i.e., Googleplus, Facebook, Twitter, Digg, StumbleUpon, LinkedIn,Delicious, Reddit, Pinterest?

Tags: javascript, button, dom-events, share, social-media

For Googleplus we can use the `callback` attribute inside the `g:plusone` tag.

```
<g:plusone size="small" callback="check_googleplus_click"></g:plusone>

function check_googleplus_click(jsonParam)
{
    alert("googleplus was clicked")
    console.debug(jsonParam);
}
```

How to check on Facebook, Twitter, Digg, StumbleUpon, LinkedIn,Delicious, Reddit, Pinterest? Any partial contribution it will be very usable.

Comment: It's not yet possible to add a callback event for StumbleUpon.

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook you can use the FB.Event.subscribe to determine when a Like Button is clicked.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
       //Do something when an user click on Like Button (to "Like" something).
       console.log(response);
    }
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (response) {
       //Do something when an user click on Like Button (to "unlike" something).
       console.log(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Here is for twitter..
    <script>
      window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
     var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
     js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
     }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
    function clickEventonTweeter(intent_event) {
    if (intent_event) {
  //write your code here
   };
 }
    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
   twttr.events.bind('click', clickEventonTweeter);
   });
```

I am now trying to find for pinterest ..